# Can we have it so that if you visit your own profile, it doesn't update the "last seen"?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, views

Note that the behaviour is obviously not so simple as "it updates each time you visit it".   From what I can see, the last-seen is updated the first time I visit my own profile, each day.

Whatever it is, can we have it so that self-view simply aren't registered?

EDIT: This question is totally mistaken about what is going on, as highlighted by the answer.  So ... never mind, I will accept the answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Last Seen" means seen on the site at all, not just that you or someone else looked at your profile.  If you come on the site at all the time will be updated.<sup>1</sup>

It appears to be per-site, not just for when you are on any Stack Exchange site.

<sub><sup>1</sup> There will sometimes be a caching delay.</sub>

Comment: Oh!   Far out - if you google/search around a bit, you will see that others are as mistaken about what this thing is as I was.  I might change my question to ask "Can we rename this to be clearer".   Hmm - is it legit to totally change a question that's already asked!? :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: It can be [kind of confusing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) if answers have already been given for the original question. Generally, it's better to ask a new question than to change a question significantly.

Comment: Yeah thanks - I concluded that.  I went and asked the question (can the meaning of the field be clarified with a better name) and got immediately downvoted into submission.   C'est la vie, at least it's still on record here :)  Now I have the Peer Pressure badge, LOL, never knew it existed!